# How to fix python pygame screen displays black

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a snake game in python pygame. I am not getting any errors but when I run my program it shows me only a black screen. I have tried to analyze my code but I think it is correct. none of my controls are working I've analyzed my code But I didn't see any problem I don't know what to do

here is my code

```
def print_score(score):
    text = score_font.render(f"Score: {score}", True, orange)
    game_display.blit(text, [0, 0])

def draw_snake(snake_size, snake_pixels):
    for pixel in snake_pixels:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_display, white, [pixel[0], pixel[1], snake_size, snake_size])

def run_game():
    
    game_over = False
    game_close = False

    x = width / 2
    y = height / 2

    x_speed = 0
    y_speed = 0

    snake_pixels = []
    snake_lenght = 1

    target_x = round(random.randrange(0, width-snake_size) / 10.0) * 10.0
    target_y = round(random.randrange(0, height-snake_size) / 10.0) * 10.0

    while not game_over:

        while game_close:
            game_display.fill(black)
            game_over_msg = message_font.render("Game Over!", True, red)
            game_display.blit(game_over_msg, [width / 3, height / 3])
            print_score(snake_lenght - 1)
            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                        game_over = True
                        game_close = False

                    if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                        run_game()
                    if event.type == QUIT:
                        game_over = True
                        game_close = False

                    

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                game_over = True
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        x_speed = -snake_size
                        y_speed = 0

                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        x_speed = snake_size
                        y_speed = 0

                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        x_speed = 0
                        y_speed = snake_size


    if x >= width or x < 0 or y >= height or y < 0:
        game_close = True

    x += x_speed
    y += y_speed



    game_display.blit(black)
    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, orange, [target_x, target_y, snake_size, snake_size])
    snake_pixels.append([x, y])

    if len(snake_pixels) > snake_lenght:
        del snake_pixels[0]

    for pixel in snake_pixels[:-1]:
        if pixel == [x, y]:
            game_close = True


    draw_snake(snake_size, snake_pixels)
    print_score(snake_lenght - 1)


    pygame.display.update()

    if x == target_x and y == target_y:
        target_x = round(random.randrange(0, width-snake_size) / 10.0) * 10.0
        target_y = round(random.randrange(0, height-snake_size) / 10.0) * 10.0
        snake_lenght += 1

    clock.tick(snake_speed)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

run_game()
```

thank ya for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to run the code **in** the application loop not after the application loop:

```py
def run_game():
    # [...]

    while not game_over:

        while game_close:
            # [...]

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # [...]

    # INDENTATION
    #-->|

        if x >= width or x < 0 or y >= height or y < 0:
            game_close = True

        x += x_speed
        # [...]
```